Kotlin error handling in Spring controllers. Is there a way to show them?
I wrote controllers on Java and really liked that I could see success and fail answers for frontend in controllers and @ExceptionHandler
    @GetMapping("/names")
    public List<MyObj> getMyObj(
            @RequestParam Integer page,
            @RequestParam Integer countPerPage
    ) throws SomethingWrongException, OtherWrongExceptions {
        return service.getInfo(page, countPerPage);
    }

But in Kotlin there is no throws so I now see info only for status "ok".
Is there any best practice for this case (except documenting by hands)?
I know about about kotlin.Result but it doesn't allow to see error types, and @Throws is too much depends on developer.

Is your question relating to documentation built from code?  Or more generally how to catch Exceptions (that occur in the Controller/Service classes, etc ) in a general way so you can produce a 400 status code and a different error schema?

@AndrewL, "Is your question relating to documentation built from code?" - Something like that but not really. I used my controllers as documentation. I could see all answers and errors (except framework related like 500, 403, 400) in one place and they would never be forgotten or misused because they are checked and controlled by java lang. Now I am looking alternative for kotlin

How about using the documentation annotation: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/kotlin-doc.html#throws-class-exception-class

Kotlin does not have checked exceptions (for details, see: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/exceptions.html ) and also (to my knowledge) provides no way to re-introduce them. You will also find that more and more java frameworks and components to use unchecked exceptions (e.g. Jakarta.validation or Spring Boot 6 exceptions).
In your specific example (on controller level), using checked exceptions in java wouldn't have any compile time effect anyhow, so the developer can still decide not to register an exception handler.
My suggestion would be to try to fit into Spring's exception handling, e.g. by creating ErrorResponseExceptions (or inheriting from it). Spring's ResponseEntityExceptionHandler will do the rest for you - or write your own ControllerAdvice (https://reflectoring.io/spring-boot-exception-handling/#controlleradvice)

Yeah, I already use ControllerAdvice. Question is more about a way to see list of possible errors for request in one place to know what to handle in frontend except common 500, 403

For documentation purposes towards a frontend, I would suggest using OpenAPI then, e.g. in @Operation. But that would be by hand again.
Alternatively, restdocs might be helpful: every error created there is automatically documented.
throws wouldn't be of help WRT frontend documentation and with both Spring and Kotlin going for unchecked exceptions, you most likely won't get what you want.
